# Date table no longer shows data when filtering dimension table in PowerBI

Tags: filter, powerbi, architecture, key, relationship

I have a data model with different fact tables which are connected to a date table and dimension table.

The fact tables have information about the number of asked questions per service per date. Questions can be asked through different mediums (e.g. phone, chat et.c) and these all have different fact tables.

The dimension table has information about the services, like the service type, name of client etc.

The date table is marked as date table in the model.

the model looks roughly something like this:[image: model overview]

All fact tables have a many to one relationship with both the Services and Dates dimension tables. They don't have relationships to each other.

The problem is that whenever I select a service from the services table as a filter, my date  table no longer shows any dates.

Unfiltered the data looks like this:
[image: unfiltered data]

but whenever I add a filter the dates disappear:
[image: filtered data]

I've filtered on the past 10 days so that it doesn't show a long list of dates, but that doesn't affect this problem. It shows the same behaviour when I delete the 'past 10 days' filter.

Does anyone understand why this happens and how I can fix this?

I have checked all relationships but they all seem correct.

Comment: Do you have bi-directional cross filtering enabled on any of your relationships?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-bidirectional-filtering

Comment: Yes that was the problem! I've changed all relationship directions to single and now it works, thanks! :)